# Having a lot of trouble understanding proof of convergence of $1/(m^k)$ , where $k > 0$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I can't understand the example my prof posted based on his definition of convergence. Everywhere I look on the internet seems to use epsilon-delta proofs but he seems to do it differently. I've been unable to wrap my head around this for days now.

Here is his definition of convergence and the **example 8.2.1** in question.

---

**§$\,8.2$ Convergence**

We say that $\{X_m\}$ *converges to a point* $p\in\mathbf{R}^n$ if the following condition holds.

$\mathbf{(C)}$ For every $\varepsilon>0$, $d(X_m,p)<\varepsilon$ for all $m$ sufficiently large, i.e., there exists a positive integer $M$ such that $$m\ge M\implies d(X_m,p)<\varepsilon .$$ In this case, we say that $p$ is the *limit* of $\{X_m\}$, and write "$X_m\to p$ as $m \to \infty$", or simply "$X_m\to p$", or "$\lim X_m =p$", or "$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}X_m=p$". A sequence is said to be *convergent* if it converges to some limit. A sequence that is not convergent is said to be *divergent*.

Noting that $d(X_m,p)<\varepsilon$ if and only if $X_m \in B(p;\varepsilon)$, $\,\mathbf{(C)}$ can be rephrased as

$\mathbf{(C)}$' For every $\varepsilon>0$, $X_m$ lies inside the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $p$ for all $m$ sufficiently large, i.e., there exists a positive integer $M$ such that $$m\ge M \implies X_m \in B(p;\varepsilon).$$

It is easy to see that a convergent sequence cannot have more than one limit. Indeed, any two (distinct) points must belong to two disjoint open balls of sufficiently small radii. Since the terms $X_m$ cannot be at once in both of these balls, the original two points cannot both be limits of $\{X_m\}$.

The first few examples mostly concern sequences in $\mathbf{R}^1$. We later will see the reason why $\mathbf{R}^1$ is practically all that we need to consider.

$\,\,\,\,\mathbf{Example}\,\mathbf{ 8.2.1. }\,$ Let $k>0$, and let $\displaystyle X_m = \frac{1}{m^k}$ for $m\in \mathbf{N}$. Then $X_m\to 0$.

Indeed, given any $\varepsilon>0$, we take a positive integer $M$ larger than $\displaystyle \left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)^{1/k}$. Then for all $m\ge M$, we have $\displaystyle m>\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)^{1/k}$, and so, $\displaystyle m^k > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$
. Therefore, $$d(X_m,0)=|X_m-0|=\left|\frac{1}{m^k}\right|=\frac{1}{m^k}< \varepsilon .$$

---

I would love any insight or help at looking at the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of any limit a fairly technical procedure whereby I give you some epsilon, and you must produce for me an M that will satisfy (or exceed) my expectations, as presented by that epsilon.

Coming up with a proof that such an M will always exist for whatever epsilon I would conceive is a form of art, but it all boils down to taking the epsilon you are given, manipulating it, and producing an M that satisfies the condition posed by the given epsilon.

In this respect, the example you've presented here is no different from any other proof of a limit I've seen. It takes the epsilon, manipulates it, and produces an M that satisfies the condition.

I'm not sure what is it that doesn't make sense to you, perhaps you can elaborate. If it is the limit itself which is being proved that does not make much sense to you, it doesn't really matter. The important thing is that if you are given a valid M for whatever epsilon you come up with, then that's indeed the limit.

Comment: To add on to this nice answer: when you prove a limit you will probably have a lot of "scratch work" where you try to convince yourself what $\delta$ you *should* pick. So reading proofs of limits can be hard, because all of that work is hidden; the proof doesn't care *why* the author chose that $\delta$, just that the $\delta$ they chose happens to work. You can either accept it as an arbitrary choice and try to read through the rest of the proof anyway, or you can try to do the scratchwork yourself and convince yourself why that was the right choice.

Comment: Thanks, I feel like these explanations might help. I'll mull it over some more tonight. I think the "scratch work" might be what was throwing me off. The limit itself makes perfect sense to me, it's mostly the M/epsilon stuff.

Comment: The epsilon is a just measure of how close to the limit value I want you to get me. So you manipulate it, and provide the necessary M that would get me there.

To understand why a certain M value was provided, you might want to try and read the proof backwards - from the point it is proved the expression is less than epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

As $m$ increases, $X_m$ decreases. So if you want to find a small $X_m$, you just need to find a large enough $m$. Let's call this $M$. Then -any- $m$ greater than that $M$ will also produce a small enough $X_m$.

Now suppose you are given $\varepsilon$ and told you need to find an $X_m$ smaller than it. Find an $M$ such that $X_m < \varepsilon$ for any $ m \geq M$. You can try this by setting $\varepsilon$ to a few known values and seeing how the $M$ varies to see if that makes the relationship make more sense.